# How do I create dependent multiple select (ManyToManyField)

Tags: python, django

```
Class Specialization(models.Model):
    spec_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

Class StudentGroup(models.Model):
    sg_number = models.IntegerField()
    sg_spec = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)
    sg_count = models.IntegerField()

Class Schedule(models.Model):
    schedule_date = models.DateField()
    schedule_spec = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)
    schedule_sg = models.ManyToMany(StudentGroup)
```

In schedule_sg I want create multiple select depending on the schedule_spec. How? I try django-smart-selects, but it not support ManyToMany feilds.

Comment: could you please explain, in layman terms, what do you mean by `create multiple select`? perhaps give a django orm or raw sql example?